# Return characters in a string in alphabetical order

Tags: python, strings, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel

## Problem

> - Take a string and return all input characters in alphabetical order
> - Assume that no numbers or punctuation will be used
> - For the same character, uppercase characters should be returned before lowercase characters
> - Do not use the `sorted` helper method
> - Do not use any libraries that are not included with Python 3.6.1

For example, `alphabetize(HelLo)` should return `eHLlo`

## Approach

1. Create a 26-element list. This list will represent the counts (uppercase 
   and lowercase) of the different alphabetical characters seen via a dictionary
2. Iterate through the characters in the input string

   1. Get the index for each character by subtracting the `int` values 
      of the lowercase character from the `int` value of `a`
   2. Get the existing count for that index & case from the counts 
      dictionary
   3. Increment the count by `1`
3. Initialize the return string
4. Iterate through each element in the list

   1. For each dictionary / element, get the character, and get the
      uppercase and lowercase counts
   2. Add the uppercase characters to the return string
   3. Add the lowercase characters to the return string
5. Return the alphabetized string

## Implementation Discussion

I know the 'Pythonic' way to accomplish this is something like 
`''.join(sorted(myString))`.

However, as somebody trying to learn Python, I wanted to use this exercise
to learn more about strings and characters in Python (for example) 
vs. Googling a one-liner (not that there's anything wrong with that).

Things I'm concerned about:

- Should this be a class? Or is it ok as a standalone method? (As 
  somebody that is more comfortable in Java, things that aren't in classes
  make me irrationally uneasy.)
- Speaking of which, there's a decent amount of stuff going on in this 
  method, should I break it up?

  - If I decide to break it up, what's the right way of 'showing' that 
    some functions are only going to be used by another function?
  - I think Python doesn't really have a concept of `private` vs. 
    `public` so do I `_(some_method_name)` here?
- What other 'Pythonic' elements am I missing (again, aside from using 
  the `sorted` method)?

## Implementation

```
def alphabetize(value):
    uppercase_key = 'uppercase'
    lowercase_key = 'lowercase'

    character_counts = []
    for i in range(26):
        character_counts.append({uppercase_key: 0, lowercase_key: 0}.copy())

    for character in value:
        index = ord(character.lower()) - ord('a')
        counts = character_counts[index]
        key = uppercase_key if character.isupper() else lowercase_key

        count = counts[key]
        counts[key] = count + 1

    alphabetized = ''
    for index, counts in enumerate(character_counts):
        character = chr(ord('a') + index)
        uppercase_counts = counts[uppercase_key]
        lowercase_counts = counts[lowercase_key]
        for i in range(uppercase_counts):
            alphabetized += character.upper()
        for i in range(lowercase_counts):
            alphabetized += character

    return alphabetized
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What other 'Pythonic' elements am I missing (again, aside from using the sorted method)?

If you want to more heavily use the standard library, you can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) along with the [alphabet constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-constants) `string.ascii_uppercase` and `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Things are also simpler if you store the counts in a dict (map) instead of the implicit map-by-`ord()`-value that you're currently using. The ordering of the counts doesn't really matter, just the order in which you output them.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
import string


def alphabetize(s):
    counts = Counter(s)

    return ''.join(
        char * counts[char]
        for char in chain(*zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase))
    )
```

---

The `counts = Counter(s)` line does essentially this:

```
counts = collections.defaultdict(int)

for char in s:
    counts[char] += 1
```

where the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (a handy class) is a dict that auto-initializes values based on the constructor you pass in, instead of throwing an exception for missing keys.

The `chain(*zip(...))` is zipping together the uppercase and lowercase alphabets, then flattening them via `chain()` into a single list, `['A', 'a', 'B', ...]`.

---

> Should this be a class?

Nope. This makes sense as a function in Python since it has no external state.

> As somebody that is more comfortable in Java, things that aren't in classes make me irrationally uneasy.

Java ties files to classes, but each Python file is already a *module*, which is a good level of encapsulation. As a very rough rule, avoid classes in Python except when you want to hold shared state, in which case class away. Or, at least, don't reach first for classes.

Comment: first of all this was very helpful, so thanks!

In case anybody else was unfamiliar with `zip` and `chain`, I'm going to walk through what I think is happening (which is fairly simple, but was informative for me).

Comment: `zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase)` returns an `iterable` of `tuple`s. Basically, `('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b')...('Z', 'z')`.

Comment: `*` [unpacks arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments). This means that `*zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase)` results in `('A', 'a')` as the first argument in the `chain` method `('B', 'b')` the second, etc.

Comment: `chain` basically [combines all input iterables into a single iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) in the order the input iterables were provided.

So in this case, since the method call looks like `chain( ('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b'),...('Z', 'z') )` the output iterable is `('A', 'a', 'B', 'b',...'Z', 'z')` as @BenC describes in his answer.

Comment: Yup, nice explanations. `zip` is a fairly common name for that function. `chain` tends to have different names in different languages. If the standard library had a flatten function, you could do `flatten(zip(...))` instead. `[char for pair in zip(uppercase, lowercase) for char in pair]` is also equivalent but IMO harder to read. We just want to alternate between iterables somehow.

Comment: I would have used `chain.from_iterable(…)` (which is basically the [`flatten`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) you are looking for) instead of `chain(*…)`. It should be more memory efficient for the same end-result.

Answer (score 5):

- The `copy()` call here `{uppercase_key: 0, lowercase_key: 0}.copy()` is redundant. `copy()` would have made sense if you had assigned this dict to a variable somewhere and were appending that variable.
- Don't use `+=` to create a big string, it can result in quadratic time.The recommended way is to create a list of such string and then join them using `str.join`. Check: [Performance tips: String Concatenation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation).
- `count = counts[key]; counts[key] = count + 1` is basically `counts[key] += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT; Disclaimer: I actually understood the sentence "return all input characters in alphabetical order" as a set question, hence my answer, which will return only one character of each type present in the input string.
I left it as is, as it could answer some use case.

---

My first take would be the following but that will only work if only all characters are in the strings, else results are strange:

```
import string

def alphabetize(inputstr):
    inputset = set(inputstr)
    refset_caps = set (string.ascii_uppercase)
    refset_mins = set (string.ascii_lowercase)
    leftcaps = refset_caps -(refset_caps - inputset)
    leftmins = refset_mins -(refset_mins - inputset)
    finalstr = list(zip(leftcaps , leftmins))
    #finalstr = str(l).strip("[']").replace("', '","")
    #Line above should be used in case you need to return a string and not a list, you can adapt the replace input to keep commas, too.
    return finalstr
```

Explanation 1:
At first I thought of making only one set, but this is forgetting that set are not ordered per se. On the other hand, they have the nice property to return characters in unicode order, hence while

```
l = [a for tuple in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase) for a in tuple]
```

returns the list in the right order,

```
s = {a for tuple in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase) for a in tuple}
```

returns capitals in alphabetical order then minuscules in alphabetical order.

So I just make substraction operations on each set separately (I remove to each reference set the difference between reference set and set from the input, which leaves basically only the set from the input, but ordered this time, for each class of characters (capitals/minuscules) and join them in the zip, and switch to a list which keeps the input order.

My second alternative is a variation on the same principle, using only one set for reference:
    import string

```
def alphabetize(inputstr):
    inputset = set(inputstr)
    prestr = [chrt for sublist in zip(string.ascii_uppercase , string.ascii_lowercase) for chrt in sublist]
    refset = set(prestr)
    leftchars = refset -(refset - inputset)

    finalstr = [character for character in inputset if character in leftchars ]
    #I could also have written directly  finalstr = [character for character in inputset if character not in (refset - inputset)]

    #finalstr = str(prestr2 ).strip("[']").replace("', '","")
    #Line above should be used in case you need to return a string and not a list, you can adapt the replace input to keep commas, too.

    return finalstr
```

My third  alternative works better, for every case:

```
import string

def alphabetize(inputstr):
    inputset = set(inputstr)
    prestr = [chrt for sublist in zip(string.ascii_uppercase , string.ascii_lowercase) for chrt in sublist]
    refset = set(prestr)
    for character in (refset - inputset):
        prestr.remove(character )      
    """but I guess it adds loads of complexity to the operation, as removing depends on length of the list -while here it is and always be limited- and is slower by conception than set operation"""

    finalstr = prestr.copy()  #or
    #finalstr = str(prestr2 ).strip("[']").replace("', '","")
    #Line above should be used in case you need to return a string and not a list, you can adapt the replace input to keep commas, too.

    return finalstr
```

In any case, I prefer this to a Counter, and intrinsicly it also avoids to use most imports (you could even avoid importing string module by just typing your list off). I think this is quite pythonic by using the sets for such operations, the encapsulated list comprehension, too.

I don't know if it is an improvement in performance, but I think lighter is better, so having less import is better. Also, using Counter is a convoluted way to do something that already exists in Python using sets as an alternative to sorting.

Else, I can't provide more justification than personal taste, but on similar performance I would prefer using set, which is more fitting my mindset to resolve such problem.

Hope this help.

I would like to timeit, but I can't, I am writing from phone.

Comment: I think I understood the question differently, hence my take with sets. I left it as is as an answer to question variation, as other people thinking like me could come here by formulating the question with similar wording...